# Notes on treble line extend down to bass line

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

What is happening when some notes extend down from the treble to the bass on this piano score? Piece is 'Wandering Sprite' by JC Engelbrecht

[image: some notes show as though they are dropping down from the top treble line down to the bass line]

Comment: Welcome! Can you clarify a bit what you mean by "what is happening"? The notes take up a beat, and some are on treble clef and some on bass. Is the question what these pitches are, or why they're beamed together? Sometimes you see something similar but with the beam between the staves.

Answer (score 6):

**All of the notes that are beamed together**, beginning in the treble stave but descending into the bass stave, **are to be played by the right hand.** As has been pointed out, it's easier to read than using multiple leger lines.

One sees this with some frequency in more advanced piano literature — the notes from one staff encroaching on another staff. It's typically clear from context, such as beaming, which hand is intended to play those notes.

Here's an example from Chopin's Etude in A minor, Op. 25, No. 11, mm. 7–8. It's clear in m. 8 that the right-hand line is continuing into the left-hand staff. An additional benefit of writing this way, beyond the absence of leger lines, is that it's easy to see that the left and right hands are playing relatively close together.

[image: Chopin op 25 no 11 mm 7–8]
(Image Source: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/%C3%89tudes%2C_Op.25_(Chopin%2C_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)), Mikuli edition)

It's slightly less common to see the left-hand part move into the right-hand staff, but it does happen. In the below example from Chopin's Etude in C Minor, Op. 25, no. 12, mm. 1–2, by extending the left hand into the right-hand staff, the relationship between the two hands' parts is made visually more clear than using leger lines or changing clefs within the left-hand staff.

[image: Chopin op 25 no 12 mm 1–2]
(Image Source: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/%C3%89tudes%2C_Op.25_(Chopin%2C_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)), Mikuli edition)

Comment: Cross-stave notation doesn't necessarily define which hand should play what.  It's just a neat way of notating a musical line when it would otherwise require a lot of ledger lines.  (Though in your examples, the hand distribution is pretty clear.)

Answer (score 3):

It means that a musical line drops below treble clef range, so rather than using lots of ledger lines it's more convenient to notate them in the bass clef.

In itself, this notation tells us nothing about which hand should play the notes.   But in this case it's pretty clear that the RH continues to play the cross-stave notes.  After all, how ELSE could it all be played?

In cases where it isn't abundantly obvious which hand plays what, a 'RH' or 'LH' instruction may be added, and the player may or not follow the suggestion.

(And it IS just a suggestion.  The composer gets to decide what notes get played, ultimately it's the player choice how to achieve them.)

Comment: Actually, all the composer gets to decide is what notes the performer should be instructed to produce.  If the performer is for whatever reason unable to perform the notes as written, the performer is going to determine what if anything gets played instead.

Comment: "It's more convenient to notate them in the bass clef" — that could be accomplished by changing the clef within the upper staff.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, that's another possibility.   But this way when the musical line goes down it LOOKS as if it goes down, which is a lot clearer to read.

Comment: @Laurence I'm saying the language in your post should be more specific. It's not just that they're notated in the bass clef, it's that they're notated in the lower staff.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a better way to write out low notes than using leger lines. At least it tidies things up, and means reading the lower notes is simpler. How one would write those lower notes on leger lines in the space usually provided beggars belief!

Comment: It would only require 4 ledger lines, which is not at all unheard of.

Answer (score 0):

I guess from that C you're supposed to just go down to Ab.

Answer (score -3):

If notes on the treble line extend down to the bass line, this means that the music contains notes that are in the bass clef register but are written on the treble staff. In this situation, the notes are played on a lower-pitched instrument, such as a bass guitar, piano, or cello, but the composer has chosen to write them on the treble clef staff for ease of reading. This technique is commonly used in music notation, particularly in orchestral or ensemble music where different instruments play different parts, and it allows the composer to convey the musical ideas clearly without having to switch between staves frequently.

Comment: No.  This is all played on piano!

Comment: Do you have a source to support any of this?  Unless the two staves were labeled with different instrument names, I would not consider this to possibly be the composer's intent.

Comment: This answer seems to discuss a different sort of situation than this question; for instance, it seems more relevant to moments in which one part contains a cue replicating another instrument's part, and some of the language seems to be about ledger lines. Was this answer perhaps generated by an AI?